# Part of the light reflection on bottle is blurred

Tags: lighting, glass, reflection, blur

I have a problem with the light reflection on the bottle. In the middle of the bottle the reflection is blurred. Does anyone know why?

[image]

Comment: hello, maybe share your file? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Hi, yes - here you go https://pasteall.org/blend/a45f0bb6bd4649fda333a512ed8f3e8c

Comment: it looks like it's just the reflection of the floor on the bottle, as the floor is rough it reflects as rough on the bottle. In the N panel > View > View, you should increase the Clip End value so that we can see something when we are out of camera view

Comment: Yes, the value should be around 600000mm. But what do I do to get the real reflection on the whole bottle?

Comment: for the Clip End you can put it at 3000 for example, if you are bothered by the big sphere, go into the Object panel > Viewport Display > Display As > Bounds

Answer (score 1):

There's no bug here, your glass is just reflecting the floor, and your floor is rough, so it's just a question of light and floor setup. If you want to have a more reflective effect, you can for example move the area light closer, or create another one, etc:

[image]

[image]